# Logarithm of singular matrix

Tags: matrices, logarithms

How do we define logarithm of a singular matrix(Say it is real square symmetric and has distinct eigen values). I tried searching online but could not find much information(Something that someone as dumb as me could understand).

MATLAB logm help says something about principal and non principal logarithm and MATLAB does give log of singular matrix. Can someone explain?

So, if I am to calculate it by hand using either decoposition into eigen value matrix and eigen vector matrices or jordan form, how do I do it?

Comment: How large is the matrix? Can you post it?

Comment: Its simple 3x3 matrix with rank=2 and I need to do everything by hand

Comment: How can you take the $\log$ of a matrix that has $0$ as an eigenvalue???

Comment: I could post the matrix but it's a question on my test so posting the actual matrix would be cheating...
But can you talk about any general nxn singular matrix?

Comment: @RobertLewis: Did you copy paste some wrong text?

Comment: @ tumchaaditya:  you mean my seeming strange comment?  If so, no. It's an in joke twixt copper.hat and myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logm.html?nocookie=true) from MathWorks says that

> If $A$ is singular or has any eigenvalues on the negative real axis, the principal logarithm is undefined. In this case, logm computes a nonprincipal logarithm and returns a warning message.

This is **poorly written**. The first part of the second sentence (about nonprincipal logarithm) actually refers to the case where $X$ is nonsingular and it has a negative real eigenvalue, but not the case where $X$ is singular. **Singular matrices have no matrix logarithms.**

A matrix logarithm of a complex square matrix $X$ is *some* matrix $Y$ such that $e^Y=X$. The eigenvalues of $e^Y$, however, are the exponentials of the eigenvalues of $Y$. Since a singular matrix always has a zero eigenvalue but $e^\lambda=0$ is not solvable, singular matrices have no matrix logarithms.

The documentation for an earlier version of Matlab is clearer, although there is still room of improvement:

> ... Complex results are produced if A has negative eigenvalues. A warning message is printed if the computed expm(L) is not close to A.
>
> ... Some matrices, like A = [0 1; 0 0], do not have any logarithms, real or complex, and LOGM cannot be expected to produce one.

Comment: But MATLAB does give a logarithm which I guess because it estimates the zero eigen value to a very small number but still not equal to zero enabling taking its log...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was quite confused because e^A=0 does not make any sense....

Comment: @tumchaaditya Yes, the command `L=logm(A)` does always return an `L` even when `A` is singular, but that doesn't mean the `L` is meaningful. If exceptional case can arise, one should call `[L, exitflag]=logm(A)` instead.